# ansible ping module failed to connect

Tags: bash, ansible

My inventory file

```
bash ~ cat inventory
```

Output

```
[webservers]
testserver ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222
```

When i try to connect

```
bash ~ ansible 127.0.0.1  -i inventory -m ping
```

It got successful

```
127.0.0.1 | success >> {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

When  i use webservers from the `inventory file`

```
bash ~ ansible webservers   -i inventory -m ping
```

It fails with the below error

```
    testserver | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error
     during the connection. We recommend you re-run the command using -vvvv, 
which will enable SSH debugging output to help diagnose the issue
```

I could figure out the this issue

Comment: Did you try adding the -vvvv flag to the end of your command to see what SSH command is being used and what errors might be produced?

Comment: your testserver | FAILED => SSH encountered an unknown error, not the webserver, please check it

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an ssh server listening on port 2222?  Your first example...

```
ansible 127.0.0.1  -i inventory -m ping
```

...would connect on port 22, because that's the default and nothing in your inventory file overrides that.

Your second example...

```
ansible webservers   -i inventory -m ping
```

...uses the following entry in your inventory file:

```
[webservers]
testserver ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2222
```

Which provides an explicit value for `ansible_ssh_port`, causing Ansible to attempt to connect on port 2222.

Comment: the port is 2222, i'm using vagrant  netstat -an | grep 2222
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.2222         *.*                    LISTEN

Comment: Are you able to manually connect with ssh to port 2222?  E.g., `ssh -p 2222 <user>@localhost`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create and exchange keys for successful ssh connection even with localhost, using the same user who will be launching the playbook.

step 1 - Generate SSH keys on the control node with the user who will be launching playbook

ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your Email address"

step 2 - copy your keys on the target host

ssh-copy-id username@hostname

step 3 - Test the successful connection via ansible ping

ansible all -m ping

Let me know incase of any issue